# Retrieve image sent via post by android in a jsp page

Tags: java, android, jsp, jsf, file-upload

I am uploading an image to the server via the Android, PHP is very simple and works well with `move_uploaded_file ()`, I do the same in java.

I did not find a way that works, someone has a way to indicate?

Below, it is the code I am using to send the image to the server android, as already remarked, because it works perfectly using the `move_uploaded_file()` php image is saved successfully!

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlServer);

        Bitmap bitmap = Util.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(imagePath, 800, 600);
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try{            
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();}
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        //Log.e("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        //  byte [] responseBody = httppost.getMethod().getBytes(); 

        String ret = "";
        //Log.e(""+response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            ret = new String(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            Log.e("RESPONSE BODY",ret);
            //Log.e("",""+EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        }
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: If all is ok then what is the question?

Comment: You actually read the question? Everything works in the Web Service in PHP, only the service that I'm doing now is in Java and this does not work!

Comment: I see no service code here. Only some code to upload a file.